# How many of these lines lie entirely in the interior of the original cube?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

A portion of a wooden cube is sawed off at each vertex so that a small equilateral triangle is formed at each corner with vertices on the edges of the cube. The $24$ vertices of the new object are all connected to each other by straight lines. How many of these lines (with the exception, of course, of their end-points) lie entirely in the interior of the original cube?

Comment: This is an interesting puzzle.  Where does it come from?  is this a homework exercise?  in what class?  What motivates the problem?  why are you interested in it? and why should *we* be interested in it?  At the very least, please indicate what you have attempted to do, and perhaps explain what tools (theorems, definitions, etc) you have access to.

Comment: Please include some context as requested in the preceding comment. If this is done the question might be reopened. Until then it should stay closed (I recommend to hold back on further deletions though).

Comment: This question has been deleted several times by now. I support the two comments above asking the OP to include some context, and maybe give some feedback/thought to the given answers. Though I am the interested party, but I think the question and the answers are worth exhibiting.

Comment: @farruhota: Not only are you an interested party, you should not even have answered this poor question in the first place. There is a reason why more people are cheating at math homework on this site than ever before. Your picture is nice but the effort should have been spent on users who actually put in effort into their question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively, consider four-storey building with $8,4,4,8$ points labeled $1$ through $24$:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

**First floor:** Number $1$ can connect with none on the first floor. $1$ can connect with $\{11,12\}$ on the second floor, with $\{15,16\}$ on the third floor and with $\{19,20,21,22,23,24\}$ on the fourth floor. So, $1$ can connect with $2+2+6=10$ points, so does each of $2-8$, hence: $8\cdot 10=\color{red}{80}$.

**Second floor:** Number $9$ can connect with none on the first floor. $9$ can connect with $\{11\}$ on the second floor, so does $10$ with $12$. Hence: $\color{red}{2}$ connections on the second floor only. $9$ can connect with $\{15\}$ on the third floor and with $\{19,20,21,22\}$ on the fourth floor. So, $9$ can connect with $1+4=5$ points on the third and fourth floors, so does each each of $\{10,11,12\}$, hence: $4\cdot 5=\color{red}{20}$. Overall, $\color{red}{22}$ connections.

**Third floor:** $13$ can connect with none on the first or second floor. $13$ can connect with $\{15\}$ on the third floor, so does $14$ with $16$, hence $\color{red}{2}$ connections on the third floor only. $13$ can connect with $\{19,20,21,22\}$ on the fourth floor. So, $13$ can connect with $4$ points on the fourth floor, so does each of $\{14,15,16\}$, hence: $4\cdot 4=\color{red}{16}$. Overall, $\color{red}{18}$ connections.

**Fourth floor:** $17$ can connect with none on the first, second, third or fourth floor. So does each other on the fourth floor.

Hence, the number of inner connections is: $\color{red}{80}+\color{red}{22}+\color{red}{18}=120$.

Comment: Another way of looking at it: since the symmetry group of the truncated cube lets you rotate any vertex on to any other vertex, once you count how many connections a single one can make (10), you can multiply that by 24 to get the number of directed connections, then divide by two because that figure counts each connection twice (once in each direction), and you get the same answer of 120. I don't know if this would be independent enough to make a good separate answer.

Comment: David Z, I assume that is what Parcly Taxel did after finding the number of inner connections. I just wanted to see through all inner connections from different perspectives. Cheers.

Answer (score 16):

In the resulting truncated cube, each vertex $v$ is incident to one triangle and two octagons, which together have $3+8+8-3-3=13$ vertices between them excluding $v$. Lines from $v$ to these $13$ vertices will not be completely in the cube; lines to the other $24-13-1=10$ vertices will. Since each connecting line is incident to two vertices, there are $\frac{24\cdot10}2=120$ interior lines.

Comment: +1 IMHO the most natural answer (also quickest, also least prone to counting error) since every vertex is the same.

Comment: One triangle and _two_ octagons. Given this mistake, can you please explain your $3+8+8-3-3$? It gets the right answer, but it looks like sheer luck...

Comment: @TonyK It's a typo, that's all!

Answer (score 8):

Every one of them that does not run along a face.

Each octahedral face of the object, of which there are $6,$ contains $8$ vertices, so there are $6{8 \choose 2}=168$ segments along those faces.  The segments that are part of the $12$ original edges of the cube are counted twice, so we subtract $12$, leaving $156$ segments on the octagonal faces of the object.

The triangular faces have segments running along them, but we have already counted those because they also run along an octahedral face.  There are ${24 \choose 2}=276$ line segments, so there are $276-156=120$ running through the body of the object.

Comment: You're double-counting octagon-octagon edges.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel:  Good point.  Fixed.  Thanks.